# About IP adresses on virtual machines

Tags: networking, virtualbox

Is there a way to create a private network and asign a ip from other country to a virtual machine.

Is for multilingual site purpouses.

I need the guest access to the host web site. Also, asign a different ip from australia, brazil or any other country to the guest in order to test different languages for the site.

Answer (score 2):

no, you cannot get a public ip assigned this way, because there is no way for you to route and reach the internet. in other words, you can assign such an ip, but it is going to be useless to you.

take a look at public vpns, proxies, or tor for pretending to be in a different country.

Comment: Good suggestion in terms of the original question. +1 for you.

Comment: It is possible if both the server and client are in the same network, which @chepe263 has control over. There is nothing that would prevent adding static routes for any given IP address.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to test multi-language support based on IP address, you're doing it wrong.

Not only is the IP 4 address space obsolete now, but the last chunks that are being sold off are split differently according to various sales agreements and auctions.

In other words, one block might be in China, another in USA, and there's no real way of knowing short of looking at the routing tables.

Add to this content delivery networks that will have similar IP ranges but offering different countries' content (e.g. Facebook), I think it's time to re-evaluate your testing scenario.

Answer (score 2):

If you setup a private network with a web server and a number of virtual PCs as clients you can use whatever IP addresses you choose. If you are running scripts on the server to detect country of origin based on IP address then if you choose appropriate addresses that also should work. You will need to implement some type of routing so that the virtual PCs can route to the server. This is probably making your testing harder than it needs to be.